# Evaluating integral using residue

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Show that $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{d \theta}{(5-3\sin(\theta))^2}= \frac{5 \pi}{32}$.

I don't quite know what zi sm doing wrong.

I simplified the expression as follows
$$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{d \theta}{(5-3\sin(\theta))^2}= \frac{1}{i} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{4z}{(3iz^{2}+10z-3i)^2}$$

From here I found the zeros to be $\frac{-1}{3i}, \frac{-3}{i}$.

I then went on to say that $\frac{-1}{3i}$ is our only pole.

Then when I plug it into the residue formula I get $$\lim_{z \rightarrow \frac{-1}{3i}}\frac{d}{dz}\left[\left(z-\left(\frac{-1}{3i}\right)\right)^{2} \frac{4z}{(3iz^{2}+10z-3i)^2}\right]$$.

And from here I am stuck. I am not sure if I messed up in my calculations or used the wrong pole or what? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? So far you did everything correct (except for notation).

Comment: Which notation is incorrect? I’m just not sure how to evaluate this limit.

Comment: Did you check my answer? Have you found your error?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost done.

Now factor the denominator of the last expression using:
$$
(3i z^2+10z -3 i)=3i\left(z-\frac i3\right)(z-3 i)
$$

Can you take it from here?

> $$\begin{align}&\lim_{z \rightarrow \frac{i}{3}}\frac{d}{dz}\left[\left(z-\frac{i}{3}\right)^{2} \frac{4z}{(3iz^{2}+10z-3i)^2}\right]\\&=-\frac49\lim_{z \rightarrow \frac{i}{3}}\frac{d}{dz}\left[\frac{z}{(z-3i)^2}\right]\\&=-\frac49\lim_{z \rightarrow \frac{i}{3}}\left[\frac{-z-3i}{(z-3i)^3}\right]=\frac{5}{64}.\end{align}$$

A side note: the integral over $z$ is not from $0$ to $2\pi$. It is $\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)dz$.

Comment: I’m not sure what to do with that? Nothing cancels out. Do I just evaluate the derivative and then take them limit? And oh yes, the integral, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: $(z−\frac i3)^2$ will cancel. After this evaluate the derivative and take the (trivial) limit.

Comment: Okay so after I take the derivative and evaluate the limit I got $\frac{i}{6}$. And then by a proposition I should be able to multiply $\frac{1}{i}(2 \pi i)(\frac{i}{6})= \frac{\pi i}{3}$ which is not the desired result?

Comment: I have added a spoiler. Can you finish now?